# How is entropy defined for a quantum field?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, entropy

I know that in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics the entropy of a mixed state $\rho$ is defined as
$$S=-k_B~\mathrm{tr}[\rho~\mathrm{ln}\rho].$$

But what about quantum field theory, or even just classical field theory?

Comment: It's the same, but how to deal with the divergences becomes its own subject.

Comment: You might find some answers here: [Aspects of Entanglement Entropy in Algebraic Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.13975), and the references it cites